# Conditional Job Chaining in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, scheduling, quartz.net, job-scheduling

Suppose that I have two jobs A and B. They both execute on different intervals which may end up overlapping. For example, if A executes every 10 seconds and B executes every 15 seconds, then every 30 seconds their execution will coincide.

I want to ensure that if their execution does end up coinciding, job A always happens first.

I'm attempting to determine a good way to set this up in Quartz.NET (2.x), but would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can set a priority value on Triggers so that if they have the same fire time, the Trigger with the highest priority is executed first.

See : http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-triggers.html

Comment: This will not solve your Problem. It only works if you have 2 Jobs and when you decrease the TaskPool to 1. Setting the Priority is needed when you have many jobs and some of them are more important than others. What do you do if a third job is needed but this job is independent from the other 2 and must executed no matter if a job runs or not?

Comment: You're correct. I just set up a Mutex to block the jobs in question, but I do still need to ensure that job A fires first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ITriggerListener` and implement the method [VetoJobExecution](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/55e01ac2-75ca-95e1-de6d-d08c120b7895.htm).
More informations can be found [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html).